# Binding selector in protractor catch the whole div instead only the value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automated-tests, protractor, ng-bind

I am using protractor for testing angular, I want to grab a value using binding selector and I get all the content of the div.

```
<div class="table-header">
     <span>{{::strategyCtrl.accountLabel | translate}}</span>
     {{::strategyCtrl.accountIdValue}}
</div>
```

For example:

`element(by.binding('strategyCtrl.strategyValue'));`

Will return the value of `strategyCtrl.accountLabel` and `strategyCtrl.accountIdValue`.

How can I get only the value of `strategyCtrl.accountIdValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `by.exactBinding` protractor element finder which checks for exact binding value. Here's how -

```
element(by.exactBinding('strategyCtrl.accountIdValue'));
```

If it still returns both values back, then you can use string functions to get the second string value returned by that element finder. Here's an example -

```
element(by.binding('strategyCtrl.accountIdValue')).getText()
.then(function(text){
    text.substring(text.indexOf(' ')); //assuming there is a space between the returned strings
});
```

Hope it helps.